# Merging two tables into new table by ID and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Let' say I have two tables:

```
table 1:

col a | col b | col c
1     | 62215 | 21
1     | 62015 | 22
2     | 62215 | 23
2     | 51315 | 24


and table 2:
col a | col b| col f
1     | 62015| z
1     | 62215| x
2     | 51315| y
2     | 62215| t
```

Where neither column a and column b are unique on their own, but the pairs (col a, col b) are all unique. How would I go about merging these two tables, to produce a

```
Table 3:
col a | col b| col c | col f
```

I want to combine these tables together, into one big table. So the new table has the values from column a and b from both tables, along with the columns unique to either table 1 or two.

I'm sure this is an extremely simple problem using MERGE or UNION but I don't use SQL at all, so I don't know how it would look like.

Thank you.

Comment: What's different between table2 and table3? Can you edit your question to show what values you'd expect table3 to have?

Comment: Whoops my bad. Table 1 contains extra columns that need to be added.

Let me edit really quickly

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? Please check the tags you select before submitting your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SELECT` statement when inserting into a table. What I would do here is write a select statement that pulls all of the columns you need first. You will have to do a full outer join (simulated by a union of left and right joins) because some pairs may exist in one table but not the other. The select would look like this:

```
SELECT t1.colA, t1.colB, t1.colC, t2.colF
FROM tab1 t1
LEFT JOIN tab2 t2 ON t2.colA = t1.colA AND t2.colB = t1.colB
UNION
SELECT t1.colA, t1.colB, t1.colC, t2.colF
FROM tab1 t1
RIGHT JOIN tab2 t2 ON t2.colA = t1.colA AND t2.colB = t1.colB;
```

Then, to insert into table 3:

```
INSERT INTO tab3 (mySelect);
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0458a/1) example.

Note that for the pairs that exist in one table and not the other, you will get `NULL` values. For example, if a row exists in table 1 and not table 2, `colF` will be null in table 3.

Comment: Perfect.

This is what I wanted.

Sorry about all the confusion, I'm completely inexperienced in anything SQL-related

Comment: @Marcin not a problem, let me know if you have any questions. If you stick with this answer, feel free to accept it so future readers know what solved your problem.

Comment: One final question: Let's say Table 1 now has > 20 columns, and and Table 2 has a large amount of columns too.

However, the same method applies: merging them by col A and col B, is there a faster way of writing it out rather than every column one by one?

Comment: @Marcin Well, you can do something like `t1.*, t2.colF, t2.colG` to shorten it, but be sure that you don't have repeated column names, otherwise you might have trouble with ambiguous column names.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the data.  Are you saying that colA and colB are unique across both tables?  do you want to join or union?

As a union:

```
Select `col a`,`col b`, `col c`, null 
from `table 1`
union
Select `col a`,`col b`, null, `col f`
from `table 2`
```

As a join:

```
Select `table 1`.`col a`,`table 1`.`col b`,`table 1`.`col c`,`table 2`.`col f`
from `table 1` join `table2` 
on `table 1`.`col a` = `table 1`.`col a`
on `table 1`.`col b` = `table 1`.`col b`
```

to insert into a table put

```
insert into `table 3`
```

in front of it.

I hope this helps.

The union would produce 1 record for every record in each of table 1 and 2.  A join will combine the data if col a and col b are the same in both tables.  I think the latter is what you want.  I didn't use a union all because that might create duplicates.